# How does this deliberate use of grammar mistakes add to one's delivery?

Tags: grammar, slang, emotions, modality

I've come across this expression used by native English speakers multiple times and excuse me for my reference to the language 'He don't give a sh*t.' Some of them are actually or at least set as being educated and cultured people. I think it must add to emotion or serve some kind of purpose? The most recent one I heard was in this video https://youtu.be/JGBMjfBgzM0
Time stamp for said expression, 11:11.

Comment: Idioms (and this is used often enough to attract that classifier) push the boundaries of either word meaning or syntax (or both). This idiom is extragrammatical, not 'a grammar mistake'. The question about pragmatics ('How does the use of X add to one's delivery) is better asked on Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This is a quote of street talk, to add emphasis: I am not giving you book talk, but the real thing.

Comment: Pragmatics **is** a branch of linguistics.